# build substrate pallet get the following fault, how to resolve it?

Tags: rust, webassembly, substrate

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
--> /Users/apple/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
|
541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
|                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type

Answer (score 6):

The latest Rust nightly is broken for MacOS.

To solve this for Substrate, run the following:

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2020-08-23
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-08-23
```

Then make sure to compile your node with:

```
cargo +nightly-2020-08-23 build --release
```

Comment: That does not work for my ubuntu:
`error: no such subcommand: +nightly-2020-08-23`